# Views List tag filtering, add a tag to a view for filtering purposes

Tags: 7, views

On the Views list `admin/structure/views`, I can filter my list of views by the tags on the View.

[image]

I can search for the tags, but how do I add my own tags to the views so that I can easily filter them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open (edit) your view
2. Click on *edit view name/description*
   [image]
3. Add to/change tags under *View tag* and click Apply
   [image]